# Send-MailMessage (1GB Attachment) PowerShell

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

Is there a way we can ginormous attachments using send-mailmessage, i tried the below snippet and it always times out., please note that its a test lab setup and mailbox related attributes are set to unlimited, so im not missing anything from admin point.

```
    PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> Send-MailMessage -From "loadtest@smetest.com" -To "loadtestuser4@smetest.com" -SmtpSe
    rver HUB -Subject hi -Attachments "C:\officesuite2010sp1-kb2460049-x86-fullfile-en-us.exe" -Verbose

    Send-MailMessage : The operation has timed out.
    At line:1 char:17
    + Send-MailMessage <<<< -From "loadtest@smetest.com" -To "loadtestuser4@smetest.com" -SmtpServer HUB -Subje
    ct hi -Attachments "C:\officesuite2010sp1-kb2460049-x86-fullfile-en-us.exe" -Verbose
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
    ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Tried below method also it still timed out

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> Send-MailMessage -From "loadtest@smetest.com" -To "loadtestuser4@smetest.com" -SmtpSe
rver HUB -Subject hi -Attachments "C:\ADCheck.ps1"
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyCont
inue
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $file = "C:\officesuite2010sp1-kb2460049-x86-fullfile-en-us.exe"
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $smtpServer = "HUB"
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $msg.From = "loadtest@smetest.com"
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $msg.To.Add("loadtestuser4@smetest.com")
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> #$msg.To.Add("administrator2@test.com")
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $msg.Subject = "Notification from email server"
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $msg.Body = "Attached is the email server mailbox report"
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $msg.Attachments.Add($att)
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $smtp.Send($msg)
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The operation has timed out."
At line:1 char:11
+ $smtp.Send <<<< ($msg)
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST> $att.Dispose()
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMETEST>
```

Comment: Are you serious, what is the interest of sending such a mail. What is the interest of testing that.

Comment: Hi @JPBlanc, we needed to test out some workload performance by sending huge files here and there to each other mailbox and record performance issues in our test tab

Comment: For me this test is just non sense. If you want to test just try to generate real flow.

Comment: Can you suggest some other way to generate traffic?

Comment: Have a look to [jetter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: Testing with a single 1GB attachment only validates that your system can handle that particular workload. If that isn't the workload of your *actual* system, then you'll learn nothing. Collect statistics & usage data/patterns for your system in a real-world environment, then model your testing after that.